# Error in the method for uploading an image with firebase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem when i going to upload an image in my database tha is in Firebase.

**This is my view xaml called: InitialPage**

```
      <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>

            <Button Text="Add Image"
                    Command="{Binding ImageDataCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

I have a button called ImageDataCommand that, when i select searches for the image in the phone gallery show an error in

`Icon.Source`

```
        private string _icon;
        public string Icon
        {
            get { return _icon; }
            set
            {
                _icon = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand ImageDataCommand => new Command(async (s) => await InsertImage(s));

        private async Task InsertImage(object s)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            try
            {
                file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions()
                {
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
                });
                if (file == null)
                    return;

                Icon.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                   var imageStream = file.GetStream();
                    return imageStream;
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

I'm using FreshMvvm and i see that one way is use x:name but in my InitPageModel not shown.

I am starting to use Freshmvvm to avoid putting code in the .cs files of classes or views.

greetings

Comment: you have defined `Icon` as a string.  Strings do not have `Source` properties.  And in the future, please post the actual error message, not a picture of a red squiggle.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the suggestion, Sorry. 

Yes, the problem is that the icon is a string, but I'm reading and a lot of people in the tutorial don't use the binding if not  x:Name="Icon".

I want use to display the image when i choose it from the gallery 
'''<Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>'''

what kind of data should I use considering that I am going to upload the photo to firebase?

Comment: just bind to the file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `Icon` from `string` to `ImageSource` .

```
private ImageSource _icon;
public ImageSource Icon
{
    get { return _icon; }
    set
    {
       _icon = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

2. Set `Icon`  directly after getting the image from gallery  .

```
Icon = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
    var imageStream = file.GetStream();
    return imageStream;
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have done it this way and it worked, thank you very much.